Move VoltaBracket in lilypond gracefully
is there way to properly move VoltaBracket so Lilypond can recalculate space?
I tried suggested settings in this page without success: https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/learning/moving-objects
What I can do is to move VoltaBracket with
\override Score.VoltaBracket.extra-offset = #'(0 . -1.6)

but that is just moving object without constrains and space is not properly recalculated.
Default state:

Moving with extra-offset:

Annotated spacing:
I would like to decrease extra-dist space as much as possible. Ideally that Opus text is almost touching VoltaBracket. How can this be achieved properly please?

Example code:
\version "2.25.16"
\score {
    \header {
        piece = \markup { \fontsize #4 \bold "Something" }
        opus = \markup { \fontsize #4 \bold "Opus text" }
    }
    \relative d' {
        \override Score.VoltaBracket.extra-offset = #'(0 . -1.6)
        \clef "treble" \time 2/4 \key bes \major \transposition bes
        \repeat volta 2 {
          \bar "[|:"
          es4. 8 d4 c bes g f2 a4 bes4 c2
          \alternative {
            \volta 1 {
              bes2~ 8[ bes8( c d)]
              \bar ":|]"
            }
            \volta 2 {
              bes2~ 4 r4
            }
          }
        }
    }
}


It looks like this is the override you want:
\override Score.VoltaBracketSpanner.padding = 0


Beautiful, thank you, actually now I use both of the overrides (Score.VoltaBracket.extra-offset and Score.VoltaBracketSpanner.padding) to get exactly what I want.

I do that occasionally too.  I use an X or Y-offset (or the like) to help LilyPond arrange the grobs, then I use extra-offset to fine tune where the grob should go.
